# liquibase cannot cast type enum to enum

Tags: postgresql, enums, casting, liquibase, psql

I currently have an enum type in my DB created via liquibase with the following script:

```
- changeSet:
      id: id_1
      author: my_team
      changes:
        - sql: CREATE TYPE my_team.letters AS ENUM ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

As I need to add letter D to the enum, I create a new enum

```
- changeSet:
      id: id_2
      author: my_team
      changes:
        - sql: CREATE TYPE my_team.letters_2 AS ENUM ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```

And I update the type

```
  - changeSet:
      id: id_3
      author: my_team
      changes:
        - modifyDataType:
            columnName: letter
            newDataType: my_team.letters_2
            schemaName: my_team
            tableName: table_name
```

And I get the following error when executing the Liquibase scripts

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/ddl-my_team-v.0.0.15.my_team::id_3::my_team team:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: cannot cast type my_team.letters to my_team.letters_2
  Position: 89 [Failed SQL: (0) ALTER TABLE my_team.table_name ALTER COLUMN case_status TYPE my_team.letters_2 USING (letter::my_team.letters_2)]
```

I can't understand why, since the destination type includes all the values of the original one.

Any way this can be done?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Postgres expert, but I think the following could do the trick:

1. Rename your column `letter` to `letter_copy`.
2. Create a new column `letter` of type `letters_2`.
3. Copy all values from `letter_copy` to `letter`. Perhaps you'll have to copy values from `letter_copy` as text like `update table_name set letter = letter_copy::text::letters;`.
4. Drop column `letter_copy`.

Now `table_name.letter` column should have a type of `letters_2` enum with all the values converted from enum `letters` to enum `letters_2`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create another enum and jump through hoops to get everything straightened.  Just [alter the existing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-altertype.html) enum:

```
 ALTER letter ADD VALUE 'D' after 'C';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but liquibase doesn't let you use that command within a changeset.

Comment: You cannot use it **within a transaction** but you can use it in a changeset. Simply use `runInTransaction="false"` and you're good to go !

Answer (score 0):

This was failing for me

```
ALTER TYPE status_type ADD VALUE IF NOT EXISTS 'NEW_ENUM_VALUE';
```

and below worked

```
--liquibase formatted sql

ALTER TYPE status_type ADD VALUE IF NOT EXISTS 'NEW_ENUM_VALUE';
```

I think the reason for the above query to work is that liquibase does not support direct updation of enum types. In order to run query natively have to use --liquibase formatted sql

https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/sql-format.html